# Improving and 'each' statement using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to improve the following code.

```
accounts = []
ids.each { |id|
  accounts << Account.find_by_id(id)
}

puts accounts
```

**How can I do?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ids` might have ids which don't correspond to real `Account`s:

```
accounts = ids.map { |id| Account.find_by_id(id) }
```

Or if you know that all the `ids` will be present, you can simplify this to:

```
accounts = Account.find(ids)
```

Comment: or for a scoped query, Account.where(:id=>ids)

Answer (score 2):

```
ids.collect {|id| Account.find_by_id(id)}
```